# Can I do cell merging in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, hadoop2, bulk-load

Suppose that I have a column that is updated incrementally other than overwriting (like a bitwise-ored integer flag or a sum column). For example (assuming only 1 version):

Existing Cell: **[key: 'k1', f1:sum: 100]**
Upcomming New Cell: **[key: 'k1', f1:sum: 200]**

Then I want to update the cell data this way: sum = 100+200 = 300.
Yielding the final record:
**[key: 'k1', f1:sum: 300]**

Here I want to **MERGE** the new cell into the old one with the same key.
How can I achieve this? A direct **put** would simple overwrite the old cell. (Again only one version is maintained).

I come up with some ideas but they don't seem satisfying though:

1> On the client side first **get** the old value then add sum to the on going **put** object.

2> Use a coprocessor. In RegionObserver.prePut I do a get, add and modify the final **put** object. This pushes the computation to the server side but still needs an extra query(get) (which could expensive) first.

Besides even the above work in real-time query scenario but what about bulk-load data merging?

I've been going through the documents for quite a while but can't find a clue yet. I'll really appreciate it if you could share some idea on this.

I'm using hbase-1.2.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly and the values are going to be long integers, then, I think that HBase increment operation should work for you. Look at the HBase 1.2.6 javadoc for [Increment](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Increment.html#addColumn(byte[],%20byte[],%20long)) for details.

If it's not the arithmetic increment that you want, HBase also has an [Append](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Append.html) operation too, which can be used to atomically append more data to an existing cell.

Note that the javacdoc mentions that Increments and Appends guarantee atomicity for writes, but not for reads, which is incorrect. They actually do guarantee atomicity for reads too (since HBase 0.95), and this was fixed in the docs in later releases.

Also, both the Increment and Append operations don't do an extra Get rpc. They work by taking a row lock on the server side and then doing a read followed by write on the server under the same lock.

Comment: In my case the new cell value to put somehow depends on the existing cell and it could be more complex than an simple incr or append. For example I have an old cell value which is an integer K and I want to update it to K_new = K ^ K' where K' is some incremental kind of value from production. I found a maybe related api: Table::checkAndPut (https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndPut-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put-). But I'm not sure how to use it. Do you think it can help? Thanks.

Comment: I think the api I listed above only helps to achieve atomic operation. In the end I must do a get followed by a put in whatever sense.